# How to multiply column by the number in ListView, Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I select data from a database.
Data in one column, you must convert to kilograms, I need to multiply by a factor of one column. The data in column `sets_weight` in the pound, and it is necessary to display in kilograms, with without modifying to the database
How to do it correctly. Any ideas! Thanks!

```
onSets = db.getSets(exesIdsColExes, toprog_dif);    
    listSets.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.itemsets, onSets, 
            new String[] {"sets_ids", "sets_weight", "sets_ones"},  
            new int[] {R.id.itemsets_ids, R.id.itemsets_weight, R.id.itemsets_ones}) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                // Here we get the textview and set the color
                Typeface fontTitleProg = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AGHELVETICA.TTF");
                TextView itemsets_ids = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemsets_ids);
                itemsets_ids.setTypeface(fontTitleProg, 1);
                itemsets_ids.setGravity(0x05);

                TextView itemsets_weight = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemsets_weight);
                itemsets_weight.setTypeface(fontTitleProg, 1);
                itemsets_weight.setGravity(0x01);

                TextView itemsets_ones = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.itemsets_ones);
                itemsets_ones.setTypeface(fontTitleProg, 1);
                itemsets_ones.setGravity(0x01);   

                return row;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So you basically want to know how to convert a column value after converting into kilogram by multiplying it with a value in another column ?

Comment: No, the data in column sets_weight in the pound, and it is necessary to display in kilograms, with without modifying to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done any android development, but [the documentation of SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) says:

> First, if a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder is available, setViewValue(android.view.View, android.database.Cursor, int) is invoked. If the returned value is true, binding has occured. If the returned value is false and the view to bind is a TextView, setViewText(TextView, String) is invoked. If the returned value is false and the view to bind is an ImageView, setViewImage(ImageView, String) is invoked.

So you just need to pass a custom instance of SimpleCursorAdapter which will, if the column index is 1 (second column), get the value in pounds from the cursor, multiply it to transform pounds into kg, set the result as the text of the view, and return true. For the other columns, return false.